# Cambiar de formato yyyy/mm/dd en sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Buenas tardes a todos.

Tengo una duda para cambiar el formato de una columna en sql oracle.

```
| TIM_VALUE|
| ----------------------------------|
| 2018-07-15T00:00:00.000+00:00     |
| 2018-12-02T00:00:00.000+00:00     |
| 2018-07-15T00:00:00.000+00:00     |
| 2018-12-02T00:00:00.000+00:00     |
```

a un formato estilo "YYYY/MM/DD"
Espero puedan ayudarme muchas gracias.

Comment: Y en concreto ¿cuál es la duda?. Te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato tiene la columna en la tabla?

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener una cadena con el formato que quieras a partir de una fecha puedes utilizar la función TO_CHAR(TIM_VALUE, 'YYYY/MM/DD')

En esta página puedes ver todas las máscaras posibles que le puedes aplicar a una fecha
[Mascaras TO_CHAR ORACLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm)